# Streamlit download button not working when trying to download files as zip

Tags: python, streamlit

I want to download images from URLs stored in an .xslx file, zip them and use Streamlit's download button to download the zip file.

Running the code without st.download_button seems to work but I don't know how to introduce the download button to my code.

The code below gives me this error message.

`RuntimeError: Invalid binary data format: <class 'zipfile.ZipFile'>`

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
import zipfile

df = pd.read_excel("images.xlsx")
# Column containing the image names
title = df["Name"].tolist()
# Column containing the image urls
images = df["Image"].tolist()

with zipfile.ZipFile("images.zip", "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as z:
    for idx,image in enumerate(images):
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(image)
        img_data = response.read()
        z.writestr(title[idx], img_data)

    st.download_button(
        label="Download Images",
        data=z,
        file_name="images.zip",
        mime="application/zip",
    )
```

Comment: `zipfile.ZipFile` is just not what it wants ("str or bytes or file"). Use the last example from https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.download_button, so a separate `with open("images.zip", "rb") as file:`

Comment: ok, added it as a proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [`st.download_button`](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.download_button) lists:

> **data** *(str or bytes or file)*

`zipfile.ZipFile` is just neither of those. However your code creates an actual `images.zip` file, and that one is a file and can be supplied as the last example (with a `flower.png`) shows on the same page. So putting the pieces together the result probably looks like this:

```
# create the file, from your code
with zipfile.ZipFile("images.zip", "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as z:
    for idx,image in enumerate(images):
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(image)
        img_data = response.read()
        z.writestr(title[idx], img_data)

# open it as a regular file and supply to the button as shown in the example:
with open("images.zip", "rb") as file:
    btn = st.download_button(
            label = "Download Images",
            data = file,
            file_name = "images.zip",
            mime = "application/zip"
          )
```